# Can not resolve reference to "package" referenced by "project"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, csproj, asp.net-boilerplate

I am trying to run the Mobile project of [ASP.NET Zero](https://aspnetzero.com/) following their [docs for Developing-Step-By-Step-Xamarin](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/documents/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Developing-Step-By-Step-Xamarin).
When I build the project, I get this error:

> XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `Abp.AutoMapper`, referenced by `Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Mobile.Shared`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Abp.AutoMapper`, or remove the reference to `Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Mobile.Shared`.

The package **Abp.AutoMapper** is installed in *Acme.PhoneBookDemo.Mobile.Shared*

and it is already referenced in the ***.csproj**:

```html
<PackageReference Include="Abp.AutoMapper" Version="4.2.0" />
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved ,  the package wasn't installed in ***.Droid**  project but installed in ***.Ios** and ***.Mobile.Shared** projects.
Installing it in the ***.Droid** project resolve the issue.

Comment: Does this mean you have to put all the references in the Droid project even for packages only referenced in the Shared project?